# Apache commons fileupload "Streaming API"

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons

I quote from Apache Commons Page for `Commons FileUpload`

> This page describes the traditional API of the commons fileupload
>   library. The traditional API is a convenient approach. However, for
>   ultimate performance, you might prefer the **faster** Streaming API.

**My Question**

What specific differences make `Streaming API` faster than `traditional API`?

Comment: The first question is too vague. By itself could make the thread get closed. The second one is the one people can actually answer...

Comment: Now I'm trying to help, don't know if the answer covers your expectations or you're looking for specific issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key difference is in the way you're handling the file, as you noticed by yourself with the factory class.

The streaming API is not saving in disk while getting the input stream. In the end, you'll be able to handle the file faster (with a cost on temporary memory)... but the idea is to avoid saving the binary in disk unless you really want/need to.

After that, you are able to save the data to disk, of course, using a bufferedinputstream, a byte array or similar.

EDIT: The handler when you open the stream ( fileItemStreamElement.[openStream](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemStream.html#openStream%28%29)() ) is a common InputStream instance. So, the answer to your "what if it's a big file" is something like this [Memory issues with InputStream in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826764/memory-issues-with-inputstream-in-java)

EDIT: The streaming API should not save to disk OR save in memory. It simply provides a stream you can read from to copy the file to where ever you want. This is a way to avoid having a temp directory and also avoid allocating enough memory to hold the file. This should be faster at least because it is not copied twice, once from the browser to disk/memory and then again from disk/memory to where ever you save it.

Comment: +1, what if the size of file is greater than what memory can hold?

Comment: Edited to answer your question (trying to)

Answer (score 0):

> The traditional API, which is described in the User Guide, assumes, that file items must be stored somewhere, before they are actually accessable by the user. This approach is convenient, because it allows easy access to an items contents. On the other hand, it is memory and time consuming.

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html

Comment: @Alfabravo I removed my comment even then I don't think this answer is worth any inside into why Streaming API is faster than traditional API?

Answer (score 0):

The streaming API should not save to disk OR save in memory. It simply provides a stream you can read from to copy the file to where ever you want. This is a way to avoid having a temp directory and also avoid allocating enough memory to hold the file. This should be faster at least because it is not copied twice, once from the browser to disk/memory and then again from disk/memory to where ever you save it.

Answer (score -1):

Streaming generally refers to a API (like Apache FileUpload or StAX) in which data is transmitted and parsed serially at application run time, often in real time, and often from dynamic sources whose contents are not precisely known beforehand.

Traditional models refer to APIs like (Traditional file handling APIs, DOM API) which provide a lot more detail information about the data.

Like for a FileHandling API Traditional approach assumes that file items must be stored somewhere, before they are actually accessible by the user. This approach is convenient, because it allows easy access to an items contents. On the other hand, it is memory and time consuming.

An Streaming API will have a smaller memory footprint and smaller processor requirements and can have higher performance in certain situations.

It works on the fundamental of "cardboard tube" view of the document you are working with.